# elasticsearch:Error: Unable to parse/serialize body

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, npm

I'm using nodejs to get data from elasticsearch. Sometimes I'm facing this while getting data.**[Unable to parse/serialize body]**. This is the sample code.

```
client.search({
index: '.data*',
size: 5000,
body: '{ "query": { "bool": { "must": [{ "query_string": { "query": "*" } }, { "range": { "Timestamp": { "gte": "2018-05-29T09:09:13.000Z", "lte": "2018-05-29T09:24:13.000Z", "format": "date_optional_time" } } }], "must_not": [] } } }'}, function(err, res) {
console.log(res);});
```

If i hit the same query in curl it works fine. Also the index can be viewed in discover page of kibana too. The issue i face is only on nodejs. I'm using elasticsearch/kibana 6.2.3. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe showing the node.js code and the queries you're making might help ;-)

Comment: Its just a normal query. ;-) `client.search({
    index: source.title,
    size: sampleSize,
    body: '{ "query": { "bool": { "must": [{ "query_string": { "query": "*" } }, { "range": { "Timestamp": { "gte": "2018-05-29T09:09:13.000Z", "lte": "2018-05-29T09:24:13.000Z", "format": "date_optional_time" } } }], "must_not": [] } } }'
}, function(err, res) {
 console.log(res);
});`

Comment: Please update your question with it and properly format your code so it's more legible

Comment: Can you give an example of response when you get the "Unable to parse/serialize" error? I have a feeling it might be the same issue as https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/20820

Comment: Other information which could be useful: which version of node.js are you using? What are your client configurations (without sensitive information)? I've been trying to reproduce the issue, albeit with elasticsaerch/kibana 6.2.4 there should both have the same node.js in Kibana's back-end.

Comment: The reason behind my issue was, the elasticsearch is behind nginix. And there was a limitation in retrieving the data. Once I increased the limit, it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Guru you should put that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind the issue was, the elasticsearch is behind **nginix**. And there was a limitation in retrieving the data. Once I increased the limit, it worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate the limits you have changed? Otherwise the answer is not helpful.